# How to store a function value into a variable nodejs server get-folder-size

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, asynchronous, promise

I am trying to find the size of the folder(contents), after digging found out the best is to use get-folder-size package. so the following code tells rest of the story:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const getSize = require('get-folder-size');
var reqSize = 0;
// This serves static files from the specified directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

getSize('videos', (err, size) => {
    if (!err) {
        console.log(size + ' bytes');
        console.log((size / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2) + ' MB');
    } else {
        throw err;
    }
});

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    //res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/test.html',);
    res.json({ title: 'zaffar', message: 'abbas', size: reqSize });
});

const server = app.listen(3001, () => {
    const host = server.address().address;
    const port = server.address().port;
    console.log('App listening at https://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

`getSize()` is printing the correct size of the folder in the console, I am struggling to store it in a variable so that i can forward/pass-on that variable to the index.html using **JavaScript to fetch the details from the server. html file** [link to fetch details from the server][1]. I want to store this obtained-size into a variable now, any help/thoughts please... .?

Comment: To be able to help you in `reqSize` you want to save the value in bytes or MB?

Comment: MB would be great, please :)

Comment: I hope it is what you are looking for, I recommend you to approve the edition that I made to your question so that it is easier to understand it for other users who have a similar problem, Welcome to Stack Overflow and happy coding!

Comment: This is perfect answer. Very much detailed, precise and complete! I don't know how to approve the edition but this is 110% perfect answer! Many thanks for your help. Cheers:)

Comment: Check this [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) and [How to approve edition](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341042/how-can-you-improve-an-approved-edit-suggestion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder size calculation is an asynchronous process, promises and callbacks are used when asynchronous processes are performed.

In this case I use promises to get the folder size when the calculation ends.

> If you do not know how the promises work, I leave this link so you can
>   read and understand.
>   [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

The `getSize()` function is the one that uses promises, the calculation runs asynchronously and when it ends it returns the value (`resolve`) or the error (`reject`).

```
function getSize() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        require('get-folder-size')('videos', (err, size) => {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            resolve({
                sizeBytes: size + ' bytes',
                sizeMB: (size / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2) + ' MB',
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Here we get the value of the promise, to get the data it is necessary to do in this way this is called *resolving the promise*.

```
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    //res.sendFile(__dirname +'/views/test.html',);
    getSize().then((data) => {
        const { sizeMB } = data;
        res.json({ title: 'zaffar', message: 'abbas', size: sizeMB });
    });
});
```

Here you have all the changes applied to your code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// This serves static files from the specified directory
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

function getSize() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        require('get-folder-size')('videos', (err, size) => {
            if (err) return reject(err);
            resolve({
                sizeBytes: size + ' bytes',
                sizeMB: (size / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2) + ' MB',
            });
        });
    });
}

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
    //res.sendFile(__dirname +'/views/test.html',);
    getSize().then((data) => {
        const { sizeMB } = data;
        res.json({ title: 'zaffar', message: 'abbas', size: sizeMB });
    });
});

const server = app.listen(3001, () => {
    const host = server.address().address;
    const port = server.address().port;
    console.log('App listening at https://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just call getSize in the app.get('/test') route?

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const getSize = require('get-folder-size');
var reqSize=0;

app.get('/test',(req,res)=>{
    getSize("videos", (err, size) => {
        if(!err && size > 0){
            reqSize = (size / 1024 / 1024).toFixed(2) + ' MB';
        }
        res.json({title:"zaffar",message:"abbas", size:reqSize});
    });
});
```